# What is the physical limit to how small semiconductors can get?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, nanoscience

Wikipedia shows [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) history of the progressive miniaturisation of semiconductors:

```
10 µm – 1971
6 µm – 1974
3 µm – 1977
1.5 µm – 1981
1 µm – 1984
800 nm – 1987
600 nm – 1990
350 nm – 1993
250 nm – 1996
180 nm – 1999
130 nm – 2001
90 nm – 2003
65 nm – 2005
45 nm – 2007
32 nm – 2009
22 nm – 2012
14 nm – 2014
10 nm – 2016
7 nm – 2018
5 nm – 2020
Future
3 nm – ~2022
2 nm – >2023
```

Is there a physical limit on how small semiconductors could get, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Well, I doubt you can get one smaller than 2 silicon atoms, so that would be a good limit, right?

Comment: @FGSUZ 2 atoms is very small, would it work? also, what would that be in nm (or picometres)

Comment: Lattice constant of silicon is 0.54 nm. A unit cell of [this lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic) contains two atoms.

Answer (score 4):

Moore's law does not describe the size of *semiconductors*, but the size of transistors on a semiconducting chip. The chip itself remains a whole piece of semiconductor, several millimeters (millions of atoms) large, but the density of transistors (i.e., the elements of computer logic) on it increases.

In principle, a [single atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-atom_transistor) (of size of about 0.1nm) could serve as a logic gate, although the necessary wiring, cooking etc. would require more place. What in reality is the crux of the Moore's law is that by now we are able to produce structures that are smaller than the electron coherence length (a few hundred nanometers), which means that we cannot use anymore the semi-classical theory if semiconductors, which served well for more than half a century, and which is grounded in boltzmann equation. Instead we need to use full quantum description - starting with [Landauer-Büttiker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer_formula) formalism for non-interacting electrons, and so on.

Comment: Where did you take the size of $0.1\,\mathrm{nm}$ from? Lattice constant of silicon is $0.543\,\mathrm{nm}$, and the nearest-neighbor distance is $a\sqrt3/4$ ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_cubic)), which is $0.235\,\mathrm{nm}$.

Comment: @Ruslan one angstrom is a typical size of atom. I didn't mention the lattice constant, because the author of the question doesn't seem to have the necessary background. Also, I don't quite believe that several nanometers sizes cited by Wikipedia are industrial standards - in the lab, sure.

Comment: [Apple A14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A14) is an example of a 5-nm SoC that's not only produced, but actually used in iPhone 12 and iPad Air 4th gen, both of which can be purchased today.

Comment: @Ruslan the way I understand it, 5nm is the minimal feature size, i.e., the resolution of the lithographic process used to build the chip. E.g., the minimal width of a wire can be 5nm, but the size of a transistor/logic gate is one or two orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: @Vadim - although the gate oxide is thinner, and perhaps more of an impediment to further CMOS scaling.